# How to avoid creating empty jar in non-Java Maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, packaging

I have a Maven project which uses a `jdeb` plugin to generate a `deb` (Ubuntu installer) package with some simple shell scripts that I would like to send to a customer to be able to deploy easily.  This project has no Java whatsoever.  I am not specifying in the `pom.xml` that it should package a jar.  However, an empty jar does get packaged in the project's `target` directory anyway.

How can I avoid creating this empty jar file?  I am not sure if it gets included in the deb package but if it does, it is just dead weight size-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured.  In the `pom.xml` the following needs to be added at the same hierarchy level where the `<name>...</name>` is for that project:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Otherwise

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

is assumed as a default.